# How to deploy a react app to a website once and forget about it

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How can I deploy a react app without having to change html scripts on my customers websites every time.

Some of my customers need a chat interface on their websites to allow website visitors to chat with a chatbot. This chatinterface is build using:

```
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0"
```

After I build the app the result is a number of bundles like this (I use lazy loading):

```
  836.16 KB  build\static\js\2.d689c593.chunk.js
  41.6 KB    build\static\js\4.23cde97c.chunk.js
  9.75 KB    build\static\js\5.8dc9a1d9.chunk.js
  4.6 KB     build\static\css\main.1434ec10.chunk.css
  2.72 KB    build\static\js\3.3feee6e1.chunk.js
  1.5 KB     build\static\js\runtime-main.06c0c5e1.js
  1.35 KB    build\static\css\3.b00b5b8e.chunk.css
  1.14 KB    build\static\js\main.5eafe177.chunk.js
  540 B      build\static\css\5.f473cde4.chunk.css
```

To make sure the app is loaded, I ask the customer to add a script to the website (or I ask for credentials and do it myself):

```
<link href="https://<myapp>.azureedge.net/static/css/main.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div id="root" role="main"></div>
    <script src="https://<myapp>.azureedge.net/static/js/runtime-main.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://<myapp>.azureedge.net/static/js/4.chunk.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://<myapp>.azureedge.net/static/js/main.chunk.js" defer></script>
```

I remove the hashes from the filenames of the chunks that are called in the script. This way I don't have to change the script every time I rebuild the app. At least in most cases I don't have to.

This works fine up untill now but takes some extra time because of manual labour (removing hashes from filenames before puring the endpoints)
Biggest drawback is the fact that as soon as the number of bundles in the build changes, I need a new script on the website of my customer.

I am looking for a way to load the chunks with hashes in the filename (to prevent cash issues from happening) without having to change the script on my customers website after each build.

I there a way to do this?

**webpack.config.**

```html
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const safePostCssParser = require('postcss-safe-parser');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const paths = require('react-scripts/config/paths');
const modules = require('react-scripts/config/modules');
const getClientEnvironment = require('react-scripts/config/env');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');
const getCacheIdentifier = require('react-dev-utils/getCacheIdentifier');
const postcssNormalize = require('postcss-normalize');

const appPackageJson = require(paths.appPackageJson);

const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

const isExtendingEslintConfig = process.env.EXTEND_ESLINT === 'true';

const imageInlineSizeLimit = parseInt(
  process.env.IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT || '10000'
);

const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes('--profile');


  const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,

        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {

        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {

          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            }),

            postcssNormalize(),
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    // Stop compilation early in production
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    entry: [

      isEnvDevelopment &&
        require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
      // Finally, this is your app's code:
      paths.appIndexJs,

    ].filter(Boolean),
    output: {
      // The build folder.
      path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,

      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,

      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      futureEmitAssets: true,
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',

      publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')),

      jsonpFunction: `webpackJsonp${appPackageJson.name}`,

      globalObject: 'this',
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {

              ecma: 8,
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,

              comparisons: false,

              inline: 2,
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
            },
            // Added for profiling in devtools
            keep_classnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            keep_fnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,

              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
        }),
        // This is only used in production mode
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {

                  inline: false,
 
                  annotation: true,
                }
              : false,
          },
          cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
            preset: ['default', { minifyFontValues: { removeQuotes: false } }],
          },
        }),
      ],
    
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        name: false,
      },

      runtimeChunk: {
        name: entrypoint => `runtime-${entrypoint.name}`,
      },
    },
    resolve: {

      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),

      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [

        PnpWebpackPlugin,
      
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
      ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [

        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                cache: true,
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                ignore: isExtendingEslintConfig,
                baseConfig: isExtendingEslintConfig
                  ? undefined
                  : {
                      extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app')],
                    },
                useEslintrc: isExtendingEslintConfig,
                // @remove-on-eject-end
              },
              loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
            },
          ],
          include: paths.appSrc,
        },
        {

          oneOf: [

            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],

                cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier(
                  isEnvProduction
                    ? 'production'
                    : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
                  [
                    'babel-plugin-named-asset-import',
                    'babel-preset-react-app',
                    'react-dev-utils',
                    'react-scripts',
                  ]
                ),
                // @remove-on-eject-end
                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent:
                            '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],

                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },

            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier(
                  isEnvProduction
                    ? 'production'
                    : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
                  [
                    'babel-plugin-named-asset-import',
                    'babel-preset-react-app',
                    'react-dev-utils',
                    'react-scripts',
                  ]
                ),

                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },

            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),

              sideEffects: true,
            },

            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: {
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              }),
            },

            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),

              sideEffects: true,
            },

            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: {
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },

            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),

              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },

          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),
      // Inlines the webpack runtime script. This script is too small to warrant
      // a network request.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5358
      isEnvProduction &&
        shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
        new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime-.+[.]js/]),
      // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
      // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
      // <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
      // It will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
      // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
      // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
      // the requesting resource.
      new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
      // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
      // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
      // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV is set to production
      // during a production build.
      // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
      // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
      isEnvDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
      // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/240
      isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
      // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
      // to restart the development server for webpack to discover it. This plugin
      // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/186
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
      isEnvProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
          // both options are optional
          filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
          chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
        }),
      // Generate an asset manifest file with the following content:
      // - "files" key: Mapping of all asset filenames to their corresponding
      //   output file so that tools can pick it up without having to parse
      //   `index.html`
      // - "entrypoints" key: Array of files which are included in `index.html`,
      //   can be used to reconstruct the HTML if necessary
      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
        publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
        generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
          const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
            manifest[file.name] = file.path;
            return manifest;
          }, seed);
          const entrypointFiles = entrypoints.main.filter(
            fileName => !fileName.endsWith('.map')
          );

          return {
            files: manifestFiles,
            entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
          };
        },
      }),
      // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
      // by default due to how webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
      // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
      // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
      // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
      // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
      // the HTML & assets that are part of the webpack build.
      isEnvProduction &&
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
          importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
          navigateFallback: paths.publicUrlOrPath + 'index.html',
          navigateFallbackBlacklist: [
            // Exclude URLs starting with /_, as they're likely an API call
            new RegExp('^/_'),
            // Exclude any URLs whose last part seems to be a file extension
            // as they're likely a resource and not a SPA route.
            // URLs containing a "?" character won't be blacklisted as they're likely
            // a route with query params (e.g. auth callbacks).
            new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$'),
          ],
        }),
      // TypeScript type checking
      useTypeScript &&
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
          typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
            basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
          }),
          async: isEnvDevelopment,
          useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true,
          checkSyntacticErrors: true,
          resolveModuleNameModule: process.versions.pnp
            ? `${__dirname}/pnpTs.js`
            : undefined,
          resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveModule: process.versions.pnp
            ? `${__dirname}/pnpTs.js`
            : undefined,
          tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
          reportFiles: [
            '**',
            '!**/__tests__/**',
            '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
            '!**/src/setupProxy.*',
            '!**/src/setupTests.*',
          ],
          silent: true,
          // The formatter is invoked directly in WebpackDevServerUtils during development
          formatter: isEnvProduction ? typescriptFormatter : undefined,
        }),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
    // Tell webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
    node: {
      module: 'empty',
      dgram: 'empty',
      dns: 'mock',
      fs: 'empty',
      http2: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      child_process: 'empty',
    },
    // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
    // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
    performance: false,
  };
};
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Please show your webpack config. You can configure the output filenames, chunking etc. there. You could for example output a single `main.js` and `main.css`, but lose the advantages of chunking. You also have to consider the browser cache, which might not refresh the files when filenames stay the same.

Comment: Thanks. I did consider this but these single files are to big for my purpose. Especially because I don't want to hurt their SEO results by loading large files.
I am looking for a way to load the chunks with hashes ((to prevent cash issues from happening) without having to change the script on my customers website after each build. Not sure however if this can be done. But I am a newbie on webdev.

Comment: A more elaborate solution I just thought of: Make a js file that does not have to change and is embedded on the client's website. It downloads a `manifest.json` (created with webpack-manifest-plugin) from your CDN, where the built files are referenced (and then dynamically loaded by your js file). This way, you can redeploy any time without the client having to do a thing.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I am looking for. Could you write this into an answer with some sample code? Or is this something everybody knows already ;-)

Comment: If everything is correctly configured, you should never need to include anything but the entrypoint chunk anyway; if you already need 3 chunks, something is not optimal with your configuration for this usecase. Either way: show your Webpack config.

Comment: Thanks. Are you referring to the one in node_modules\react-scripts\config? That thing i s huge. Are there specific parrs that are relevant or do I just share the whole thing.

Comment: If you're working with `create-react-app`, you have to run `npm run eject` in order to eject the webpack config first. And yes, it will be pretty big.

Comment: tnx. I added the webpack config. Had to remove a lot of comment since it is to big to be saved with this post.

Comment: @Taxel would the manifest generated by webpack-manifest-plugin be any different than the asset-manifest.json in the build folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `create-react-app` for this, there's no need to eject the `webpack.config.js` (since this is irreversible, I hope you have a git commit you can revert). So here's the general gist:

- You create a file called `chatLoader.js` **outside of your react project** (if you don't intend to learn how to configure this in the same webpack config, which might get a little tricky) and add babel transpilation and minification by yourself.
- This file contains something like (untested)

```
/**
 * Loads a javascript file asynchronously
 * @param {string} url must be valid in <script async src=
 * @returns {Promise<HTMLScriptElement>}
 */
function loadScriptAsync(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = () => resolve(script);
    script.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`could not load script ${url}`));
    script.async = true;
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  });
}

function loadStyleAsync(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const link = document.createElement("link");
    link.href = src;
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.onload = () => resolve(link);
    link.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Style load error for ${src}`));

    document.head.append(link);
  });
}

async function fetchManifest() {
  // TODO: add error handling for production code!
  const res = await fetch("https://your-url/path/asset-manifest.json");
  const text = await res.text();
  return JSON.parse(text)["entrypoints"]; // we only want to load the entrypoints from this file
}

(async() => {
  // this is the main function
  const entries = await fetchManifest();
  for(const entry of entries){
    // this is loading all entries at once, not waiting for the first entry to be loaded before taking the next one
    if(entry.endsWith(".css")){
       loadStyleAsync(`https://your-url/path/${entry}`)
    } else if (entry.endsWith(".js")) {
       loadScriptAsync(`https://your-url/path/${entry}`)
    }    
  }
})();
```

You can (when you get the `chatLoader.js` to work) just embed this one file into your client's code and it should preload the latest build of your React app.

Comment: Tnx. I will give  this a go and accept the accept the answer if I get it to work. Given all the warnings out there I decided not to eject

Comment: Thanks. Got it working without any hazzle. Looks like an elegant solution to my problem. I will check the impact on performance and stability for a while and after that use it for my deployments